# Looking for a collection of applications of the Open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am looking for various applications of the open mapping theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis) )  other than only the closed graph theorem and that if two comparable norms make a space Banach then they are equivalent . Any Journal or Book reference or any links are highly appreciated . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for functional analysis applications only?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1650443/254733